# Can't keep onboarding screens clear with context

Tags: react-native, react-context

I have an onboarding screen in my app that I want to dismiss with a button press either at the end of the process, or to skip the process entirely.

I was planning on using `context` to do this that will use `react-native-encrypted-storage` to store the acknowledgment locally on the phone, and also `useState` to switch to the rest of the app afterward.

The issue I am finding is that, although pressing the button to acknowledge or skip the process works to hide the onboarding on that instance... If I close the app, remove it from the running apps and reopen it, I am greeted again with the onboarding screens...

I'm wondering if there is anything I am doing/missing from my process.

**storageUtils**

```
const getItem = () => async (key) => await EncryptedStorage.getItem(key);
const storeItem = () => async (key, val) => await EncryptedStorage.setItem(key, val || '');
```

**onboardContext**

```
export const obContext = createContext({
    onboarded: !!getItem('onboard'), // Should this be here?
    handleOB: null
});

export const useOBContext = () => useContext(obContext);

export const obProvider = ({children}: any) => {
    const [onboarded, setOB] = useState(false); // Should this be !!getItem('onboard')?

    const handleOnBoarding = async () => {
      storeItem('ONBOARDED', 'true');
      setOB(true);
    };

    return (
      <obContext.Provider value={{onboarded, handleOB}}>
        <Text>onboarded: {onboarded.toString()}</Text> {/* Just for visual testing */}
        {children}
      </OnBoardingContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

**navigation**

```
const {onboarded} = useOBContext();

    return (
        <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName="OnBoarding"
            screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
        >
            {!onboarded && <Stack.Screen name="onboarding" component={Onboarding} />}
            <Stack.Screen name="main-app" component={MainApp}  />
            ...
```

**onboarding**

```
const {handleOB} = useOBContext();

return (
    <View>
        ...
        <Button onPress={handleOB}>skip</Button>
        ...
```